# Is it possible to create and use custom System::String^ extension methods in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

I tried making an extension to the built-in String class using C++/CLI, and using it from C++/CLI without success.

Here's the simplest I can boil it down to:

```
[System::Runtime::CompilerServices::Extension]
public ref class MyStringExtensions abstract sealed {
    public:        
        [System::Runtime::CompilerServices::Extension]
        static bool TestMethod(System::String^ str) { return false; }
};
```

Now, when I try to use this in other C++/CLI code, I get a compiler message indicating that TestMethod is not a method of String.

```
String^ foo = gcnew ...
...
blah = foo->TestMethod();  // compile-error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Extension functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922112/c-extension-functions) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919715/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-c-sharp-style-extension-method-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463009/extension-methods-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't have extension methods.

But it does have [ADL (Argument-dependent lookup, also known as Koenig lookup)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) which is arguably even nicer.

Comment: So this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012578/how-can-i-create-net-extension-methods-by-c-cli is invalid?

Comment: No, it's different.  That one covers definition of extension methods in C++/CLI, not calling them from C++/CLI.  C++/CLI doesn't know anything about extension methods (you can still use normal static method syntax), and the C++ idiom is to use an overloaded free function instead.